# Calculation gives the wrong result

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract

After doing a simple calculation in rust ink! 4.0 smart contract, the result is incorrect and doesn't match the expected result.

Here is the simple formula:

```
let a0_balance_mul:U256 = U256::from(amount_in_with_lp_fees * self.get_a0_balance());
```

The variables for the above formula are:

1. `amount_in_with_lp_fees = 100,000,000,000,000,000,000`
2. `self.get_a0_balance() = 10,000,000,000,000,000,000`

The result that Im getting is : `319,435,266,158,123,073,073,250,785,136,463,577,088`
Which should be : `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

I've checked both numbers and they are both represented correctly using `U256` int.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I should've converted both `amount_in_with_lp_fees` and `self.get_a0_balance()` into `U256` int, they were `u128`.